# how do I create a query of neo4j using the neography ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography, graphenedb

According to the [documentation on querying nodes](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Phase-2-Nodes) for the neography ruby gem:

```
Neography::Node.find(index, query)   # advanced query of the node index with the given query
```

But I am unclear what the format and examples of the `query` is above.

What I want to do is provide a search term that then queries all nodes that have, as one of the properties, `userID = xxxx`.

I am using a hosted neo4j database on grapheneDB.

For example I want to find the nodes that are relative to a given node:

- Relationship = friends
- Date Created = yesterday
- Limit = 1

Comment: FYI (and you might already be aware), but Neography has been largely abandoned ([check the commit history][1]). I'd definitely recommend checking out the [neo4jrb][2] or more minimal neo4j-core gems (even the neography readme suggests neo4jrb). I started with Neography before quickly making a switch and am *really* pleased with neo4jrb. Neo4j-core would be the direct comparison to Neography. [1]: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/graphs/contributors [2]: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Since `neography` is a wrapper around the Neo4j REST API, you can refer to the documentation there. See: [17.10. Find node by query](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-find-node-by-query).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at it now....but it's unclear what I am actually passing: and do I need to use the escape characters in the query string?